# use BootstrapHorizontalForm in yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod, yesod-forms

I intend use a BootstrapHorizontalForm, use how example this [guide](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-form-1.4.3.1/docs/Yesod-Form-Bootstrap3.html#t:BootstrapFormLayout), my code:

the form

```
churchForm :: Maybe Church -> AForm Handler (Church,Maybe FileInfo)
churchForm mc = (,) <$>
(Church
 <$> areq textField (bfs MsgName) (churchName <$> mc)
 <*  bootstrapSubmit (BootstrapSubmit MsgCreateAction "btn-default" [("attribute-name","attribute-value")])
```

the GET method

```
getChurchNewR :: Handler Html
getChurchNewR = do
(widget, enctype) <- generateFormPost $
                   renderBootstrap3 (BootstrapHorizontalForm (ColSm 0) (ColSm 4) (ColSm 0) (ColSm 6))
                   (churchForm Nothing)
  defaultLayout $ do
    msgAction = MsgCreateAction
    actionR = ChurchNewR
    mPath = Nothing
$(widgetFile "church/church")
```

but have this error:

> Handler/Church.hs:63:67: Not in scope: data constructor ‘ColSm’

thanks for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a missing import. Check that you actually import `CpmSm` at the top of your file.

This import could be of the form:

```
import Yesod.Form.Bootstrap3 (BootstrapGridOptions (ColSm))
```

or

```
import Yesod.Form.Bootstrap3 (BootstrapGridOptions (..))
```

or even

```
import Yesod.Form.Bootstrap3
```

If that doesn't sound familiar, you can take a look at [the modules chapter from *Learn Yourself a Haskell*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules) to know more about imports.

Comment: thanks for the answer and the link, the problem was the imports,